# How to bypass all the prompts while overwriting the ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

We have one project and have to overwrite the project in the same name using ionic start command, but we stuck at overwrite prompt.

We tried `-y`

`ionic start sampleproject -y sidemenu --cordova --type=ionic-angular --no-deps`

But in that case the after -y commands not working and  we have to choose the starter template manually again.

Comment: did you try `ionic start sampleproject sidemenu --cordova --type=ionic-angular --no-deps` ??

Comment: yes, but its prompting me like overwrite or not . i want the script without manual inputs.